# Converting Formatted Date String Using toLocaleString Method To Timestamp Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, date, datetime, timestamp, timezone

I need to convert datetime html input data to a timestamp after I have used the toLocaleString method to format the date's time zone.

HTML

```
<input
  type="datetime-local"
  class="form-control my-2"
  id="dateTime"
/>
```

Javascript

```
const dateTimeInput = document.querySelector("#dateTime") 
// Output Example: 2022-08-02T13:32

const date = new Date(dateTimeInput.value).toLocaleString('en-CA', {
    timeZone: 'Canada/Eastern',
}) 
// Output: Tuesday, August 2, 2022 at 07:32:00 Eastern Daylight Saving Time
```

I've tried using the `getTime()` method after using `toLocaleString`

How do I convert my formatted date and time string to a timestamp (in milliseconds) after setting the timezone of the date?

Comment: You don't.  Unix timestamps *always* in terms of UTC.  Asking for one in terms of another time zone is nonsensical.

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint should I then used an offset in milliseconds instead of converting the date to suite a different timezone?

Comment: No, that's not a good idea because it wouldn't handle DST properly.  I believe I understand what you're asking for though. See my answer below.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in comments, one can't ask for a Unix Timestamp in terms of another time zone because Unix Timestamps are always in terms of UTC.

*However,* you can interpret the *input* value in another time zone, and obtain a UTC-based Unix Timestamp from that.  I *think* that's what you're asking for.

Unfortunately, JavaScript can't do this by itself yet.  The [Temporal proposal](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/) will be adding better support for time zones, but until that is widely available you will need to us a library to handle the conversion.  I'll use [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon) in this example, but there are others.

```js
const dateTimeInput = document.querySelector("#dateTime");
const timeZone = 'America/Toronto';

dateTimeInput.addEventListener('change', () => {
  
  // This creates a Luxon.DateTime object from the given inputs
  const dateTime = luxon.DateTime.fromISO(dateTimeInput.value, {
      zone: timeZone
  });

  // And here we can output some values from that
  console.clear();
  console.log('Original Input:', dateTimeInput.value);
  console.log(`Assigned to ${timeZone}:` , dateTime.toString());
  console.log('As a Unix Timestamp (ms):', dateTime.toMillis());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/3.0.1/luxon.min.js"></script>
<input type="datetime-local" id="dateTime" />
```

Also note I used `America/Toronto`, which is the [canonical form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) of `Canada/Eastern`, but either would work.

Comment: Thank you so much Matt! This works and is concise. Would you mind checking out my other question on creating groups based object property values if you can?

Comment: If this answered your question, you should upvote and accept.  Please read [*What should I do when someone answers my question?*](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). Thanks.

Comment: I'm still new to be an active member but working towards getting enough reputation in order to do so. Please read [Why are 15 reputation points required to upvote?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41347/why-are-15-reputation-points-required-to-upvote)

Comment: True for the upvote, but you'll get [2 points just for accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).